# how to i add a javascript file in magento 2 module and how to call it in phtml?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, extensions, requirejs, requirejs-config.js

I try to add custom java-script file but giving error of different kind, please give me a proper example of adding **JS** in **Magento 2** module and use it in phtml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `requirejs-config.js` under `app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend` and the below code:

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom: 'Vendor_Module/js/custom',
        }
    }
};
```

This will add custom.js no need to add .js extension. Now add your custom.js to the below directory

> app/code/[Vendor]/[Module]/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js

Now you can use your js function on phtml by using below code:

```
 <script>
    (function  () {
        require(["jquery","custom"],function($) {
            $(document).ready(function() {
                // Your code
            });
        });
    })();
</script>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: actually i add this but how to use in phtml file like alert pop up

Comment: I have shared you the phtml code as well. You can add alert under $(document).ready.

Comment: i follow this but getting error in console in static file this is not found: custom.js not found in static files folder 404

Comment: and also /magento2/pub/static/version1527655585/frontend/Magento/luma/en_US/custom.js:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: Did you add the Js under web directory?

Comment: yes add the js in view/frontend/web/js folder

Comment: Can you check if the custom.js is present after the static content deploy to your relative directory under pub/static/frontend

Comment: not found custom.js file pub root

Comment: hi man thanks i upgrade the magento and run di and static deploy command its run.

Answer (score 0):

Create new custom.js file under :

> /app/design/frontend/Vendor/YourTheme/web/js/custom.js

```
require([
'jquery',
'owl.carousel'
], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
         // Your Custom Code here
    });
});
```

---

Create New requirejs-config.js under your theme

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*' : {
            'owl.carousel' : 'Vendor_Module/js/owl.carousel'
        }
    },
    deps: [
        "jquery",
        "custom"
    ]
};
```

**In PHTML file :**

```
<script>
   require([
       'jquery',
       'owl.carousel'
       ], function($){
           $(document).ready(function() {
                // Your Custom Code here
           });
       });
</script>
```