# i have added the custom js in the magento 2 module but giving 404 error in static folder!

Tags: magento2, extensions, phtml, requirejs-config.js

I've added all thing like require-js and script in custom but not worked.Please show me path with correct example of bootstrap in Magento 2.

[image]
my require-config.js is

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom: 'Pfay_Contacts/js/test',
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Give some brief info. Where you added js and do you run deploy command?

Comment: i added the require js in Vendo/Modul/view/requirejs-config.js and add custom js in the view/frontend/web/js/ folder also add js reference in <head> tag in default.xml  but not working

Comment: Can you update your question with code?

Comment: Share your requirejs-config.js file content

Comment: var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom: 'Pfay_Contacts/js/test',
        }
    }
};

Answer (score 0):

Create new custom.js file under :

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/web/js/custom.js

```
require([
'jquery'
], function($){
    $(document).ready(function() {
         // Your Custom Code here
    });
});
```

---

Create New requirejs-config.js under your theme

> /app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/requirejs-config.js

```
var config = {
    map: {
        '*': {
            custom: 'Vendor_Module/js/custom',
        }
    }
};
```

**In PHTML file :**

```
<script>
   require([
       'jquery',
       'custom'
       ], function($){
           $(document).ready(function() {
                // Your Custom Code here
           });
       });
</script>
```

Comment: i am talking about module not theme.

Comment: I think you have already raised question in  https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/227831/how-to-i-add-a-javascript-file-in-magento-2-module-and-how-to-call-it-in-phtml/227848#227848

Comment: yes but not solved i follow all step but result not as desire.

Comment: I have updated my comment

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not run static-content:deploy Please run the following command:

**For Production Mode:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade (if you have added new module)

php bin/magento setup:di:compile (if you inject something to your module)

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy (if you have changed css/js etc)
```

**For Developer or Default Mode:**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade (if you have added new module)

php bin/magento setup:di:compile (if you inject something to your module)

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f (if you have changed css/js etc)
```

Comment: You dont need to call these commands in developer mode. Only flush the cache.